# Image change onclick not work in mobile browser

Tags: jquery, mobile

I have a code that will change the image upon clicking on the image. However, since I am using mouseup/mousedown, is there a way to make it so that it also work in mobile browsers as well?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".menulink").eq(0).mouseup(function(){
        $('#menu1').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/333/3ef/img/picture2.jpg');
  });
  $(".menulink").eq(0).mousedown(function(){
        $('#menu1').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/333/fe3/img/picture1.jpg');
  });
  $(".menulink").eq(1).mouseup(function(){
        $('#menu2').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/333/3ef/img/picture2.jpg');
  });
  $(".menulink").eq(1).mousedown(function(){
        $('#menu2').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/333/fe3/img/picture1.jpg');
  });
});
```

Here is the [fiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/Wdwdz/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use `touchstart` and `touchend`. I also made this slightly more efficient, hope you don't mind.

```
$(function(){
    var $menulink = $('.menulink'),
        $menu1 = $('#menu1'),
        $menu2 = $('#menu2');

    function setSrc($menu,$src){
        $menu.src = $src;
    }

    $menulink.eq(0).on({
        'mouseup touchstart':function(){
             setSrc($menu1[0],'http://placehold.it/333/3ef/img/picture2.jpg');
        },
        'mousedown touchend':function(){
             setSrc($menu1[0],'http://placehold.it/333/3ef/img/picture1.jpg');
        }
    });

    $menulink.eq(1).on({
        'mouseup touchstart':function(){
             setSrc($menu2[0],'http://placehold.it/333/3ef/img/picture2.jpg');
        },
        'mousedown touchend':function(){
             setSrc($menu2[0],'http://placehold.it/333/3ef/img/picture1.jpg');
        }
    });
});
```

This might be even more efficient, and is especially helpful if you have more than just the two.

```
$(function(){
    var $menulink = $('.menulink');

    for(i=$menulink.length;i--;){
        var $menu = $('#menu'+(i+1))[0];

        $menulink.eq(i).on({
            'mouseup touchstart':function(){
                 $menu.src = 'http://placehold.it/333/3ef/img/picture2.jpg';
            },
            'mousedown touchend':function(){
                 $menu.src = 'http://placehold.it/333/3ef/img/picture1.jpg';
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Just another option to consider.

Comment: haha man, i just checked it today and realized i used commas instead of colons. my tips wouldn't have worked! should be good now.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: don't use `click`

Yes, you  use `touchstart` and `touchend`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Jonathan's answer, also checkout https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch which applies the touch events to their mouse counterparts.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will check it out. :)