# html image onclick does not working on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

This code is working properly when it is running in a computer browser, but it is NOT working when it is running on mobile browser, the onclick event is not recognized:

```
<div align="center" style="float:right; padding-top:5%; margin-right:20%;">
    <input type="image" src="images/btn_rgest.png" style="width:100%;" onclick="check_phone();return false;"/>
</div>
```

I also tried (ontouchstart) event but alst not working.
any help?

Comment: this may helpfull to you..http://stackoverflow.com/a/17353104/3164682

Comment: its onClick="" typo in your code.